# Unable to get Count in lambda expression - NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, notsupportedexception

I am trying to get the number of subjects each student have using the below query:

```
var selectedSubject = context.Students
                             .Include(d => d.Subjects)
                             .Select(dr => new
                                           {
                                               Name = dr.Student.FirstName,
                                               NoOfSubject = dr.Subjects.Count
                                           })
                             .ToList();
```

But I am getting an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Subjects' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your Students and Subjects models?

Comment: We need to see your model definitions. EF is telling you that `Subjects` is not queryable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to access non `entity member` Properties on the `IList` interface (like `Count`) until the query is materialized.

Either materialize early:

```
var selectedSubject = context.Students
                         .Include(d => d.Subjects)
                         // .Where() goes here, 
                         .ToList()
                         .Select(dr => new
                                       {
                                           Name = dr.Student.FirstName,
                                           NoOfSubject = dr.Subjects.Count
                                       })
                         .ToList();
```

Or, make use of the `Count()` method, which will be mappable into Sql:

```
var selectedSubject = context.Students
                         .Include(d => d.Subjects)
                         .Select(dr => new
                                       {
                                           Name = dr.Student.FirstName,
                                           NoOfSubject = dr.Subjects.Count()
                                       })
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var count = context.Students.Select(x=>new { Name = x.Student.FirstName, 
    NoOfSubject = x.Subjects.SubjectId.Count}).ToList();
```